# discovering nearby Bluetooth devices showing nothing

Tags: c#, bluetooth, xamarin.android, prism, dryioc

I'm new to `Xamarin`, as a beginner task, I asked to show a list of nearby active Bluetooth device(in **Android only**). without using any `NuGet` package (**except Prism**)

I followed [this manual](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2018/12/16/how-to-detect-nearby-bluetooth-devices-with-net-and-xamarin-android/) and also looked [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83113/how-to-discover-local-bluetooth-devices) for my references
in my `OnReceive` function i do get   `BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted` and `BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished` but not the `BluetoothDevice.ActionFound`

I started a new prism template app with **dryioc container**

I'm running the app on my phone OnePlus A6003(Android 9.0 - API 28), and I have 2 ready to connect Bluetooth devices, one on my old phone and on my laptop(windows 10) and I checked them both if they can pair to my device and all worked fine

**in my AndroidManifest.xml** i added

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**my BroadcastReceiver class**

```
public class BluetoothDeviceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public static BluetoothAdapter Adapter => BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var action = intent.Action;
            // Found a device
            switch (action)
            {
                case BluetoothDevice.ActionFound:
                    // Get the device
                    var device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);

                    // Only update the adapter with items which are not bonded
                    if (device.BondState != Bond.Bonded)
                    {                       
                    }
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted:

                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished:

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**and my mainActivity**

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            var coarseLocationPermissionGranted =
                 ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation);
            var fineLocationPermissionGranted =
                ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation);

            if (coarseLocationPermissionGranted != Permission.Denied ||
                fineLocationPermissionGranted == Permission.Denied)
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, LocationPermissions, LocationPermissionsRequestCode);

            // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
            _receiver = new BluetoothDeviceReceiver();          

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
        }


        private void RegisterBluetoothReceiver()
        {
            if (_isReceiveredRegistered) return;

            RegisterReceiver(_receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound));
            RegisterReceiver(_receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted));
            RegisterReceiver(_receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished));
            _isReceiveredRegistered = true;
        }

        private static void StartScanning()
        {
            if (!BluetoothDeviceReceiver.Adapter.IsDiscovering)
                BluetoothDeviceReceiver.Adapter.StartDiscovery();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            StartScanning();

            // Register broadcast listeners
            RegisterBluetoothReceiver();
        }
```

what am I missing?
restarting my phone or the other devices did not work

Comment: From your code ,not found problem where is.Just can recommend a sample to test whether can work first.

Comment: what do you mean by "Just can recommend a sample to test whether can work first? –"?

Comment: Sorry for missing the sample link.(https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/BluetoothTISensor).

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT i dont want to use any BT nuget packages

Answer (score 2):

From your code ,you have set `permission` in `AndroidManifest.xml` .Maybe the problem is also the permission, there are two way to choose to try:

**One is easy**, just need to set `targetSdkVersion` Less than 23.

**Two**，need to add permissions dynamically like `OnCreate()` method:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) != Permission.Granted)
                {
                    RequestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation }, 1);
                }
            }
```

And in request to do what you need do:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 1:
                // todo request success  
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }
```

Comment: i will try but does it differ from my permission check?

Comment: From Android 6.0 need permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` .However, if also not work ,somebody use like this way can solve this problem.Not sure this be worked for you,but can have a try.